# radio button not sending values through ajax

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

it's a star rating system that i'm trying to send via user, includes a comment on the product and a rate from 20 = 1 star, 40 = 2 stars, etc...
no matter which star the user submits it's only taking the first value (100 = 5 stars) here's the code :

```
<input id="star5" name="star" type="radio" value="100" class="radio-btn hide" />
<label for="star5">☆</label>

<input id="star4" name="star" type="radio" value="80"
    class="radio-btn hide" />
<label for="star4">☆</label>

<input id="star3" name="star" type="radio" value="60"
    class="radio-btn hide" />
<label for="star3">☆</label>

<input id="star2" name="star" type="radio" value="40"
    class="radio-btn hide" />
<label for="star2">☆</label>

<input id="star1" name="star" type="radio" value="20"
    class="radio-btn hide" />
<label for="star1">☆</label>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-main" id="commentbtn" onclick="comment()" > Send </button>
```

And here's the ajax code :

```
function comment() {
        var comment = $('#comment').val();
        var star = $('input[name=star]').val();
        var product_id = '<?php echo $productID;?>';
        var username = '<?php echo $_SESSION["username"];?>';
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "comment.php",
            data: {
                comment: comment,
                product_id: product_id,
                star: star,
                username: username
            },
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data) {
                swal({
                    text: "comment has been submitted",
                    icon: "success",
                    button: false,
                    timer: 1500,
                });
                $(document).ready(function(e) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        window.location.href = "single.php?product_id=" + product_id
                    }, 1500)
                });
            },
            error: function() {}
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because `$('input[name=star]')` selects all the radio inputs, and trying to retrieve the value from a jQuery collection will always return the value from the first element only. This is why the value you get is always `100`.

To fix this use the `:checked` selector to retrieve only the value the user has selected:

```
var star = $('input[name=star]:checked').val();
```

Comment: thank you so much brother problem solved by Adding **:checked** .

Comment: No problem, glad to help